# Need a little CSS advice

Tags: css, internet-explorer, navigation, suckerfish

I have created a modified version of the suckerfish navigation for a personal project. It looks and performs exactly as I want it to. However, it completely degrades in IE. I spent all day yesterday trying to find a solution with no luck. So I thought I would ask some sharper minds than my own. I am open to just about anything right now. As it stands the page is valid HTML and CSS.

Thanks in advance.

The Navigation can be found here:

http://rachalconsulting.com/assets/samples/

The style sheet is here:

http://rachalconsulting.com/assets/samples/style.css

Comment: Your link to the stylesheet doesn't work.  It should be http://rachalconsulting.com/assets/samples/style.css

Comment: one thing - which version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same problem, and the solution turned out to be to use the [csshover.htc file](http://www.tanfa.co.uk/css/examples/menu/tutorial-h.asp).

Comment: Thanks. I've actually been trying to use the whatever:hover method, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I added the script file and then the assigned the behavior to the body tag, and nothing.

Comment: Did you add the csshover.htc file to the head element?  I did something similar here: http://www.stannscatholicschool.com. Take a lok, let me know if that helps.